# Expressions... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, expression, argumentexception

I've decided to take some golden time to learn a bit more about Expressions. I'm trying a very simple exercise, namely adding two numbers. I've hit an exception that's proving to be tricky to search for.

Here's my code

```
Expression<Func<int,int,int>> addExpr = (x, y) => x + y;
var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p1");
var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p2");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int,int,int>>(addExpr, p1, p2); //<-here
var del = lambda.Compile();
var result = del(2,3); //expect 5
```

but this is throwing an ArgumentException : Expression of type 'System.Func`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Int32'

at the line indicated above. What have I done wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do in this code? Are you trying to build (x,y) => x + y lambda using expressions only?

Comment: Just poking around. Ultimate goal is an exercise to write a Countdown numbers game solver. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_%28game_show%29#Numbers_round Seems to me that expression trees would be a good means of tackling this, but it's all very new and shiny to me ATM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the `addExpr` in an invoke using the expression parameters

```
Expression<Func<int,int,int>> addExpr = (x, y) => x + y;
var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p1");
var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p2");
var invokeExpression=Expression.Invoke(addExpr,p1,p2);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int,int,int>>(invokeExpression,p1,p2);
var del = lambda.Compile();
var result=del(2,3);
```

The invoke is how you type p1 to x and p2 to y, alternatively you could just write the above as

```
var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p1");
var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p2");
var lambda=Expresion.Lambda<Func<int,int,int>>(Expression.Add(p1,p2),p1,p2);
var del = lambda.Compile();
var result=del(2,3);
```

Otherwise you need to grab the expression body into the lambda and pass the expression parameters.

```
var lambda=Expresion.Lambda<Func<int,int,int>>(addExpr.Body,addExpr.Parameters);
```

Comment: Gotcha. All falling into place now.

Comment: @Spender and after all that I've added a final update as the third option. This option will work if you do not need to use the expression parameters from elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to present some alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Expression<Func<int, int, int>>, int, int>(addExpr, p1, p2);
```

Your current code expects an `int` and your passing in `Expression<Func<int, int, int>>`.

**Update**

Actually the above won't compile, you would need to do:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, int>>(Expression.Add(p1, p2), p1, p2);
```

Comment: Yeah, that is not going to work, unless you compile and call the passed expression.

Comment: @leppie yeah I just tested the code there, I have updated my answer to use `Expression.Add` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decompose `addExpr`'s body or preferably just write it from scratch ie `Expression.Add(p1,p2)` instead of `addExpr`.

Comment: What does "decompose" even mean? Pretend I have rep 0!

Comment: @spender: decompose == take apart ie `addExpr.Body`

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting there now.